# How to execute SQL script in directory from another script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Say I have a .sql script stored in `c:\scripts\some_script.sql.`

What command do I use to execute this script from within another script or stored procedure.

For example

```
create procedure dbo.sp_execute_script
    @script_location varchar(100)   
as  
    execute(@script_location)

 -- does not work  
go
```

I am running the scripts in SSMS.

Comment: You want to run `c:\scripts\some_script.sql`, and that in turn should call another script - is that the case? Where is the `create procedure` code supposed to be?

Comment: sp_execute_script is a stored procedure.  Within this Stored Procedure, i will like to run the script located in "c:\scripts\some_script.sql"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `xp_cmdshell` to run `sqlcmd` utility to execute your script:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'SQLCMD -S <Server> -E -i "C:\path\script.sql"
```

Comment: Thank you.  Just what I needed.  Used this link to be able to execute xp_cmdshell:  http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-enable-xpcmdshell-stored.html